# c# WinForms accessing instance from another class

Tags: c#, forms, instances

I'm facing this problem (i'll make it short and easy)
In form1 i need to create an instance of Login form and be able to access it in the class abc and use it's(login's) method.However, it appears to be inaccessible.

I hope i said all the relevant in an understandable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally to do exactly what you ask, you need to provide an instance of `Login` to `abc`, for example by passing it in through the `abc` constructor.

You may wish to consider refactoring some of the functionality currently in `Login` form to make it useful in all places it's needed.

I suggest having a look at the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  While WPF, Silverlight and ASP.Net MVC provide strong support for that pattern, you can certainly apply it in a [WinForms scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406/looking-for-a-mvc-sample-for-winforms) as well.

Using a pattern like MVC will make your code far easier to evolve and maintain over time.

Comment: Thank you very much! Understood the logic and made it working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling actual functionality belonging to another form explicitly, it is possibly time to look at your design. You should probably have a class or assembly dealing with authentication which is decoupled from any form. Use it in both your login form and class ABC.